# Failure to connect to MongoDB - couldn't connect to server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, mongodb

I am using a reverse-ssh tunnel to make a DB behind firewall available from remote machine. But here is the intriguing part:

From AWS server with ssh tunnel to DB behind firewall: connecting to IP and PORT Connects successfully

From remote machine: connecting to the same IP and PORT Couldn't connect to server

AWS security group settings allow connections to given port. Question: how do I troubleshoot?

Comment: Is the was address natted. Is it the same internally as externally, are you using cloudfront? Can you ping it?

Comment: @PaddyCarroll, I have missed the basics!!! The internal AWS IP was different from its real one! Stupid me. Thank you very much. Would you like to post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the AWS address natted. Is it the same internally as externally, are you using cloudfront? Can you ping it.

Comment: I have missed the basics!!! The internal AWS IP was different from its real one! Stupid me. Thank you very much